# Trying to convert Global.asax 1.0 file to 3.5 Issues with Application_Error + Session and Redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net-3.5, session-variables, global-asax

So in the Global.asax is this:

protected void Application_Error(object sender, System.EventArgs
            {
   Session["CustomError"] = Server.GetLastError();
   Server.ClearError();
   Response.Redirect("~/ErrorPage.aspx");
      }

And in ErrorPage.aspx is this:

private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
  {
   Exception currentException = ((Exception)Session["CustomError"]).InnerException;

// Writes the error message
   if (currentException != null)
    txtErrorMessage.Text = currentException.Message;

// Loops through the inner exceptions.
   currentException = (Exception)Session["CustomError"];
   while (currentException != null)
   {
    message.Append(currentException.Message).Append("\r\n").Append(currentException.StackTrace);
    message.Append("\n==============================================\n");
    currentException = currentException.InnerException;
   }

As this is old 1.0 code it barfs when converted to a 3.5 Global.asax file. It tells me that "Session" is not available and also that I can't redirect?? I think one of the issues may be that there is also an error being thrown from Application_Start. But if I comment out all the application start code I still get errors but they never get redirected to the error page.

Answer (score 0):

This link might help: [Exceptional Gotchas!](http://blog.theobjectguy.com/2009/12/exceptional-gotchas.html).
In addition, use the web.config file to define your default redirect page for errors.